# how to make an absolutly positioned input shrink to fit?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<ul>

    <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a><input type='text' value='whatever' /></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item 4</a></li>

</ul>
```

1. The input is positioned absolutly.
2. The ancestor li of the input is positioned relatively.
3. The input has opacity 0 and is a static element, but needs to be there.
4. There will only ever be 1 input (with type text), in the list at any time.

I would like to make the `input` tag shrink to fit the li.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hacky perhaps, but you could try this:

```
input{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 24px or whatever you need
}
```

Each edge will be against the matching edge of the parent element.

Comment: ohhh i like this little hacky thing haha :) ive never tried using two separate positions before, but it works a treat! - Any ideas about browser compatibility?

Comment: Older versions of IE might have issues. Everything else should be fine, I've used this trick on a fairly important corporate site and nobody has come looking for my head yet.